# How to get MSI GF65 Thin to Wake on LAN?

Tags: remote-desktop, wake-on-lan

I have an MSI GF65 Thin laptop, and I would like to put it in another room with the lid closed, and simply wake it when needed, and access it via RDP (using MSFT Remote Desktop).  I'm on Windows 10 for both the laptop and the desktop I want to access it from.  Both machines are on wired ethernet and on the same subnet as everything else in the home.

RDP works fine as long as the machine is awake, but I can't get WoL to work at all.  Here's what I have already done, in no particular order:

- Enabled WoL in the NIC
- Enabled WoL in the BIOS
- Forwarded port 9 UDP in my router
- Added an Inbound rule for port 9 UDP in Windows firewall
- Tried 2 different WoL applications to send the packet
- Started the Simple TCP/IP Service

Ultimately I would like to be able to have the lid closed, but currently I can't get it to work even with the lid open.  The machine is in sleep, not hibernate.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh I knew I had missed something.  In addition to enabling WoL in the NIC, you have to expressly go into the power management tab of the NIC and check the box to allow the NIC to wake the computer.  Every little thing counts!

Answer (score -1):

I have a VECTOR GP66 and I can't get wake on lan to work, can you tell me in the BIOS what settings you changed? I only find a setting called WAKE ON LAN ON S5 and nothing else..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).